# How to get the default Session for an Estimator in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've created an Estimator and exported it to a SavedModel file using the Estimator's `export_savedmodel()` function.

For reproducibility reasons, I would like to be able to re-create the Estimator, load the variables in the SavedModel file then call `evaluate()` and get the same results.

I thought the way to do this is to create my SessionRunHook to do the loading and pass it to the hooks parameter in `evaluate()`, like so:

```
class myhook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):

    def begin(self):
        tf.saved_model.loader.load(tf.get_default_session(), ['serve'], '../best_model/1516075471/')


load_best_model_hook = myhook()

res2 = da_model.evaluate(test_input_fn, hooks=[load_best_model_hook])
```

But this gives the following error:

```
File "/home/user7891/Code/scratch.py", line 106, in begin
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(tf.get_default_session(), ['serve'], '../best_model/1516075471/')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 198, in load
    with sess.graph.as_default():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'graph'
```

It looks like a session was not created when `begin()` was called. I can't override `after_create_session` because the graph can't be modified at this point.

Comment: What's wrong with `model_dir` argument in `Estimator`?

Comment: `model_dir` only works with checkpoints  and not with SavedModel from the
`export_savedmodel()` function. I train my model for many epochs and track and save the model that gives the highest accuracy. I don't save every checkpoint file so the model that gave the highest accuracy may not have a checkpoint file.