# How to download TensorFlow trained model on Google Colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, model

I am a newbie and researching about Machine Learning, I have created a model on `Google` `Colab`.

My goal is to use that model for offline predicting in an Android app. So I need to download the trained model.

The only thing I know is I need to save my model as a `.pb` file in order to make my Android app. I have searched around, maybe there are answers but they were too short for me to understand
So need very detail answers.

[This](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kmT0Fhby7TEKPcARGXu1fGaYWCZmUmhG#scrollTo=moUbKF6G7pFp) is my `Test.ipynb` file, Can someone spend a little bit time to train that model and see if we can download it to local drive.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I save and download model files from Collab.

1. Save only the **trainable variables**(These are my store/restore fns):

code is as below :

```
def store(sess_var, model_path):        
    if model_path is not None:
        saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.trainable_variables())
        save_path = saver.save(sess_var, model_path)
        print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)
    else:
        print("Model path is None - Nothing to store")



def restore(sess_var, model_path):
    if model_path is not None:
        if os.path.exists("{}.index".format(model_path)):
            saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.trainable_variables())
            saver.restore(sess_var, model_path)
            print("Model at %s restored" % model_path)
        else:
            print("Model path does not exist, skipping...")
    else:
        print("Model path is None - Nothing to restore")
```

2. Compress the directory where you stored your model - Make sure it contains nothing else: `!tar -czvf model.tar.gz models/`
3. Download the model:

   `from google.colab import files
   files.download('model.tar.gz')`

Since your only storing the trainable variables instead of the entire session, the size of the model is small and thus it is able to download. Be sure to use `Chrome` - I've not been able to get the last snippet working on Firefox.

Comment: I'm not sure why Stackoverflow isnt able to properly format my python code - if someone could help out with that it would be great.

Comment: Hello, what does "where you stored your model" mean? I have the following error:

tar: models: Cannot stat: No such file or directory

tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: Assuming  you stored your `.pb` file in a directory called `models` do the above step. My point is just compress whatever is generated `saver.save` and download it from Collab.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't have that .pb file anywhere in my local drive, all the things are running on Google Server. Maybe I don't get what you meant. Can you please write something that will work anyway?

Comment: The .pb or `protobuf` file is what is stored by `tf.train.Saver` on your Collab machine. I've given you the code already. You can assume  the `model_path` you pass to the `store` function I've provided above is `models/my_model.pb` and `sess_var` is the session variable.

Comment: How to get my session variable?

Comment: Oh I see your using the `tf.Estimator`. This is a high level API which gives little low level control to the programmer. I've never used it - so you'll have to probably try something like provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286968/how-to-get-the-default-session-for-an-estimator-in-tensorflow. In any case once you store the model - you can follow the rest of the provided steps.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from google.colab import files


# Specify export directory and use tensorflow to save your_model
export_dir = './saved_model'
tf.saved_model.save(your_model, export_dir=export_dir)
```

Note that the export directory contains several files, but if you only want to download the .pb file the following should do it.

```
# Download the model
files.download(export_dir + '/saved_model.pb')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
!mkdir -p saved_model
saved_model_dir = 'saved_model/my_model'
model.save(saved_model_dir) 

#Convert the model

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir) 

tflite_model = converter.convert()

#Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

From the [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/convert/convert_models#convert_a_savedmodel_recommended_).

Answer (score 0):

```
model.save("your_model.h5") #save your model as a file
#check if your_model.h5 is here with ls command then download
!ls
from google.colab import files
files.download('your_model.h5')
```

**NOTE: I imported following these before:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```